# Converting Int to String using map function in pandas

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, anaconda-cluster

```
dmap = {0:'Mon',1:'Tue',2:'Wed',3:'Thur',4:'Fri',5:'Sat',6:'Sun'}
df['DayOfWeek']=df['DayOfWeek'].map(dmap)
df.head()
```

[DayOfWeek column value is Showing as NaN rather then String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HnJ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question exactly but i guess it has to be something like that

```
dmap = {0:'Mon',1:'Tue',2:'Wed',3:'Thur',4:'Fri',5:'Sat',6:'Sun'}
       count = 0
       df = pd.DataFrame({'DayNumber':[], 'DayOfWeek': []})
       for key, value in dmap.items() :
           df.loc[count] = [str(key) , value] 
           count = count + 1 
       print(df.head())
```